# Android Studio Google Maps only shows grid lines with new API key

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, release

I am totally confused about creating and installing a Google Maps (release) apk file! I have checked *Build Variants* in Android Studio to show *Release* then generated a new Certificate.
Then I ran the java keytool on this certificate and obtained the SHA1 key which pasted in https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_android_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE_ANDROID&reusekey=true

The resulting key was added to the *manifest.xml* at the bottom like so (as it says on the Google page):

```
  <meta-data
  android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
  android:value="myGeneratedKeyHere"/>
```

This crashes the app, although it did run, but with only grid lines (no map) when I just had the key entered in the *main.xml*
file. 
Google say that
*Existing keys from a Google Maps Android v1 application, commonly known as MapView, do not work with the current (v2) API.*

What does this mean? I am using Mapview so what must I do please please?

Comment: add your java and xml code also

Comment: Having done a lot more Googling I realise that Mapview cannot be used and I must use MapFragment so I will try whatever that is.